# No responise to expect send after successful match and send

Tags: expect

I'm trying to write an expect script, the prompt I am expecting to handle is `ade 123456789: / >`.  The number 123456789 will change, so I though I could just match on the only > I'm expecting to receive.  I can't seem to get it to work however.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 3
set uuid [lindex $argv 0]
spawn telnet localhost 1402
expect ">"
send "/proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID $uuid"
```

Calling the script with `expect.sh my_uuid` in debug gives me the following output.  It seems to send the command but I don't see the output, whereas I do if run manually.

```
expect version 5.45.4
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = ./expect.sh  argv[3] = 1234ABCD-ABCD-123A-123A-123456ABCDEF  
set argc 1
set argv0 "./expect.sh"
set argv "1234ABCD-ABCD-123A-123A-123456ABCDEF"
executing commands from command file ./expect.sh
spawn telnet localhost 1402
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {1905}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ade 123456789: / >"? no
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
ADE 4.1 - Console Ready.

ade 123456789: / > 
expect: does "Trying ::1...\r\nTrying 127.0.0.1...\r\nConnected to localhost.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nADE 4.1 - Console Ready.\r\n\u001b[K\r\nade 123456789: / > " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ade 123456789: / >"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "ade 123456789: / >"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Trying ::1...\r\nTrying 127.0.0.1...\r\nConnected to localhost.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nADE 4.1 - Console Ready.\r\n\u001b[K\r\nade 123456789: / >"
send: sending "/proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 1234ABCD-ABCD-123A-123A-123456ABCDEF" to { exp4 }
```

Comment: You need to add a carriage-return to the sent string: `send "...\r"`.

Comment: Also, your script is just falling off the end: even if you hit Enter as meuh suggests, you're not giving the telnet process a chance to respond. End the script with `interact`

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I added `\r\n` and it did help.  I didn't want to interact as I wanted to capture the next prompt and exit afterward.  I do get the response now but then prompt looks different in the debug output than it does onthe console.

```ade 123456789: / > /proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 1234ABCD-ABCD-123A-123A-123456ABCDEF

{"ERROR":""}
ade 123456789: / > 
```

```
/proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 1234ABCD-ABCD-123A-123A-123456ABCDEF


spawn id exp4 sent <{"ERROR":""}\u001b[K\r\n>
{"ERROR":""}
spawn id exp4 sent <ade 123456789: / > ade 123456789: / > >
```