# Duplicated response using expect that doesn't occur when run manually

Tags: expect

I've been trying, [with a little help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810824/no-responise-to-expect-send-after-successful-match-and-send) to create an expect script to query a service via telnet.

Sometime the response is received with two system prompts concatenated together in the expect debug response [2].  This doesn't display when done manually[1], can anyone suggest why this is the case?

Here is the expect script, which I call with `expect.sh UUID`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 3
set uuid [lindex $argv 0]
spawn telnet localhost 1402
expect ">"
send "/proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID $uuid\r\n"
expect ">"
sleep 1
send "exit\r\n"
interact
```

[1] Console output

```
# telnet localhost 1402
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
ADE 4.1 - Console Ready.

ade 123456789: / > /proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-0123-0123-0123-012345678912

{"ERROR":""}
ade 123456789: / >
```

[2] Expect debug output

```
expect version 5.45.4
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = ./expect.sh  argv[3] = 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012  
set argc 1
set argv0 "./expect.sh"
set argv "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"
executing commands from command file ./expect.sh
spawn telnet localhost 1402
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {30855}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
ADE 4.1 - Console Ready.

ade 123456789: / > 
expect: does "Trying ::1...\r\nTrying 127.0.0.1...\r\nConnected to localhost.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nADE 4.1 - Console Ready.\r\n\u001b[K\r\nade 123456789: / > " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) ">"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Trying ::1...\r\nTrying 127.0.0.1...\r\nConnected to localhost.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nADE 4.1 - Console Ready.\r\n\u001b[K\r\nade 123456789: / >"
send: sending "/proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012\r\n" to { exp4 }

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
/proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012



expect: does " /proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012\r\n\r\n\u001b[K\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
{"ERROR":""}

expect: does " /proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012\r\n\r\n\u001b[K\r\n{"ERROR":""}\u001b[K\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
ade 123456789: / > ade 123456789: / > 
expect: does " /proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012\r\n\r\n\u001b[K\r\n{"ERROR":""}\u001b[K\r\nade 123456789: / > ade 123456789: / > " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) ">"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " /proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012\r\n\r\n\u001b[K\r\n{"ERROR":""}\u001b[K\r\nade 123456789: / >"
send: sending "exit\r\n" to { exp4 }
tty_raw_noecho: was raw = 0  echo = 1
spawn id exp4 sent <exit\r\n\r\n\u001b[K\r\n>
exit


spawn id exp4 sent <Connection closed by foreign host.\r\n>
Connection closed by foreign host.
interact: received eof from spawn_id exp4
tty_set: raw = 0, echo = 1
tty_set: raw = 3, echo = 0
expect version 5.45.4
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = ./expect.sh  argv[3] = 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012  
set argc 1
set argv0 "./expect.sh"
set argv "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"
executing commands from command file ./expect.sh
spawn telnet localhost 1402
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {30865}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...

expect: does "Trying ::1...\r\nTrying 127.0.0.1...\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

expect: does "Trying ::1...\r\nTrying 127.0.0.1...\r\nConnected to localhost.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
ADE 4.1 - Console Ready.

ade 123456789: / > 
expect: does "Trying ::1...\r\nTrying 127.0.0.1...\r\nConnected to localhost.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nADE 4.1 - Console Ready.\r\n\u001b[K\r\nade 123456789: / > " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) ">"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Trying ::1...\r\nTrying 127.0.0.1...\r\nConnected to localhost.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nADE 4.1 - Console Ready.\r\n\u001b[K\r\nade 123456789: / >"
send: sending "/proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012\r\n" to { exp4 }

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
/proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012


expect: does " /proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012\r\n\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no


expect: does " /proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012\r\n\r\n\u001b[K\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? no
{"ERROR":""}
ade 123456789: / > ade 123456789: / > 
expect: does " /proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012\r\n\r\n\u001b[K\r\n{"ERROR":""}\u001b[K\r\nade 123456789: / > ade 123456789: / > " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) ">"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " /proc/OBRP/ObjectByUUID 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012\r\n\r\n\u001b[K\r\n{"ERROR":""}\u001b[K\r\nade 123456789: / >"
send: sending "exit\r\n" to { exp4 }
tty_raw_noecho: was raw = 0  echo = 1
spawn id exp4 sent <exit\r\n\r\n>
exit

spawn id exp4 sent <\u001b[K\r\n>

spawn id exp4 sent <Connection closed by foreign host.\r\n>
Connection closed by foreign host.
interact: received eof from spawn_id exp4
tty_set: raw = 0, echo = 1
tty_set: raw = 3, echo = 0
```

Comment: ".sh" is an odd extension for an Expect program.

Comment: What do you mean by "formatted oddly"? Do you mean "why am I seeing all the debug output? That happens due to the `-d` option. Do you mean "why do I see the prompt twice? That's because you `send` with `\r\n`. Just `\r` is idiomatic for "hitting Enter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the debug output, you can see that the ">" command prompt is repeated. This can cause your script to lose track of what it should be doing.

The reason the prompt is repeated is because the `send` commands end with `\r\n`. Each of these characters is converted to a newline, so it is like sending 2 commands, the second one being an empty line.

You should end each command with just `\r`, which corresponds to typing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The output you get back will have `\r\n`, which is normal.